# Iterated Integral

Tags: definite-integrals

I look for an argument to this statement:

$$
 \int_a^x dx_1  \int_a^{x_1} K(x_1,t) dt= \int_a^xdt \int_t^x K(x_1,t) dx_1
$$
It is certainly an integration by change of variables that I can not clarify

Comment: Do you see the domain..?

Comment: $K\ge0$?       $\,\,\,\,$

Answer (score 2):

$a\leq x_1\leq x$ and $a\leq t\leq x_1$. So, one has that $t$ changes from $a$ to $x_1$ and $x_1$ changes from $a$ to $x$. It is the same that $t$ changes from $a$ to $x$ and $x_1$ changes from $t$ (it is more than $\min(a,t)=t$) to $x$(it less than $x$).
You can draw a picture and everything will be evident.

Comment: When changing the order of integration in a double definite integral, always draw a picture of the region.